# Python class attribute seems to be resetting

Tags: python

I have 2 files here, one is a player.py

```
class playerinfo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.playername=None
        self.authtoken=None
```

And in the main file I've got

```
from player import *
p=playerinfo()
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def login(self, Username, Passwd):
        if logindata != "11":
            p.playername=Username
            p.authtoken=logindata[0]


class PlayerScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PlayerScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    print(p.playername)
```

My problem is in the PlayerScreen class p.playername returns as None as set in playerinfo()
If I print p.playername in the MenuScreen class it prints out the playername correctly.

Comment: What else do you think should `p.playername` return?

Comment: Whatever I set it to with p.playername=Username

Comment: Please check the coding conventions for python, too. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @AndrewBerry: but you print `p.playername` *during class definition*, before `MenuScreen().login()` is called.

Comment: Did you mean for it to be printed as part of the `PlayerScreen.__init__()` method? You don't show where you call `MenuScreen().login()`, nor where you create an instance of `PlayerScreen`, so we can't tell you what to fix here either.

Comment: You are dead on @MartijnPieters I'm creating the instance of PlayerScreen() before running MenuScreen.login() Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I'm new to OOP in python.

Comment: @AndrewBerry: if your indentation as posted here is correct, then it doesn't matter when you create the instance, the `print` is executed as part of defining the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

- the `print` statement is executed as part of the body of the `PlayerScreen` class. It is indented to the wrong level to be part of the `__init__` method.

  You are mixing tabs and spaces in that part of the code making it possible that this is an accident. *Don't mix tabs and spaces for indentation*, you'll only get into more issues, configure your editor to expand tabs to spaces.
- If the indentation is not correct in your question and `print` is part of the `__init__` method, then you must be creating the `PlayerScreen()` instance before `MenuScreen().login()` is run, triggering the `print` before a playername has been set.